# Onclick Google map popup Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, onclick

On clicking a button should show the google map in popup wizard, which is the concept i am working on. 
 And my code is,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $(".geocode").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var lat = $("#lat").val();
        var lng = $("#lng").val();
        var path=$("#title").text();
        var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                zoom: 18,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
        var map = new google.maps.Map($("#dvMap")[0], mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map: map
        });
    });
});
//});
</script>
```

But I don't know how to do popup in this. I am completely blank. Can someone help me to get rid of this.

Thanks!.

Comment: can you post the fiddle of the code? With only this much data it is not easy to find the mistake.

Comment: And i don't see any code for the popup here.

Comment: I don't know how to include a popup code in this.. @SoorajChandran

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


     var lat = $("#lat").val();
    var lng = $("#lng").val();

    function WinOp()
    {   popup = window.open("", "", "height=300, width=700, top=300, left=300, scrollbars=1")    
        popup.document.write('<div id="map-canvas"></div>')
        popup.document.close()
        return false;
    }

    function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

     }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @shilpa sree But still same issue

Comment: And I want this on click event